# .htaccess with php to load randomfile

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm using apache2 and latest php what I want to do is load a random URL php file on my domain.

Example: `example.com/randfilename.php?var1=1&var2=2&var3=3`

Then the randomfilename.php will load file.php with vars. Keep in mind randomfilename.php will not be that name is will be random with .php at the end.

I tried with `RewriteEngine` and it only works for me for `example.com/randfilename` but once I add .php it doesn't work.

What I have tried is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z\-]+)$ file.php?key=$1 [L]
```

Is there another away of doing this to achieve what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.php` extension has a `.` in it, and your pattern is `^([a-zA-Z\-]+)$`, which matches only letters and dashes, no periods. You can explicitly add the `.php` extension to the pattern and exclude `file.php`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/file\.php$
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z\-]+)\.php$ file.php?key=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I didn't think the pattern would effect it. Works now thank you!

Comment: On the `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z\-]+)` how would I go about just letting any chars through? I filter them through php is there a security risk to allow any chars?

Comment: @AbbyE To let anything through, use `^(.+)`. The `.` is a regex reserved character meaning "any character except a newline"

Answer (score 0):

What `^([a-zA-Z\-]+)$` actually means is "match a-zA-Z- from start to end". Since ".php" has  a dot it won't match.

This should do it.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z\-]+)\.php$ file.php?key=$1 [L]
```